# oracle How to display the sum of top 10, the sum of the rest, the difference

Tags: sql, oracle

How to display  the sum of top 10, the sum of the rest, the difference

I don't know how to do it, I can rank them in order, but don't know what is the next step.

My table is like

```
name area
a     10
b     23
c      3
...
```

Comment: anyone who hasn't sleep......?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to number records from 1 to N (where N is last), 
and then sum first 10 and the rest based on these numbers.
The easiest way to do it is to use `wor_number` analytic function, see the documentation for details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Your query migh look like:

```
SELECT SUM( column_to_sum ) sum_of_all,
       SUM( CASE WHEN nbr BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN column_to_sum END ) as top_10,
       SUM( column_to_sum )
       - 
       SUM( CASE WHEN nbr BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN column_to_sum END ) difference
FROM (
     SELECT column_to_sum,
            row_number() OVER 
                 (ORDER BY expression_to_order_rows_from_top_to_bottom) nbr
     FROM table
)
```